# force Django tests to write models into database

Tags: python, mysql, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am setting up a very simple Django project and with a very simple test like:

```
def test_name(self):
    t = Thing.objects.create(name='a')
    print(t.id)
    import time
    time.sleep(30)
    self.assertEqual('a', t.name)
```

The tests passes of course, but the database (`TEST` database) doesn't get populated with my `Thing` model information, even though I can actually see its `id` as you can see my script.

When I connect into the database, the `Thing` table is always empty (I also saw some comments about it in the documentation).

Now, how can I tell Django to actually populate the data? I am using mysql, and checking the complete logs I see Django is creating a `SAVEPOINT` before populating data (that is not committed) and once the test passes, it goes back into that previous `SAVEPOINT`.

I am using:

```
Django==2.0.1
mysqlclient==1.3.12
pytest==3.3.2
pytest-django==3.1.2
```

I would like Django to actually populate the `TEST` database, with the information from my tests and at the end drop that database, that's why I am assuming Django is creating a completely new database just for tests.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for the hint. Yeah but I want something more general, if I could disable that entirely for all the tests, like in the settings file, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pendant to the `django.test.TransactionTestCase` for pure function tests is the marker

```
pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
```

from `pytest-django`. Example (with the `sqlite3` backend):

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_model_written_to_db():
    obj = MyModel.objects.create(name='foo')
    assert obj.id == 1
    conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/mytestdatabase.sqlite3')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM backend_mymodel")
    assert len(cur.fetchall()) == 1
```

If you want to apply the marker automatically to all tests, you can do that with a custom `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook. In your `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        item.add_marker(pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True))
```

Now you can remove the `pytest.mark.django_db` marker from the above test and it will still behave the same.

However, custom hooks or `pytest` fixtures don't work for the `unittest`-style testcases subclassing `django.test.TestCase`, so your best bet would be indeed subclassing `django.test.TransactionTestCase`, as suggested [Ghariani Mohamed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5048667/ghariani-mohamed) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511886/2650249).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the django TestCase class, which subclasses the TransactionTestCase class, the database will always be reset to the original state.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase

Comment: the closest solution would be for me to use `TransactionTestCase` for all my tests.